# Oracle: Is there a way to get the column data types for a view?

Tags: oracle

For a table in oracle, I can query "all_tab_columns" and get table column information, like the data type, precision, whether or not the column is nullable.

In SQL Developer or TOAD, you can click on a view in the GUI and it will spit out a list of the columns that the view returns and the same set of data (data type, precision, nullable, etc).

So my question is, is there a way to query this column definition for a view, the way you can for a table? How do the GUI tools do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `user_tab_columns` (or `all_tab_columns` and `dba_tab_columns` respectively) regardless if table_name refers to a view or a table.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I swear I queried all_tab_columns where table_name=my view name and didnt get any results... I must have had a typo in my query or something, because I just tried it again and got results. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

View columns appear in `all_tab_columns`, so you can query them just as you can tables.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply write this query:

```
SQL> desc TABLE/VIEW NAME;
```

For example if the table/view name is "department" Then just write:

```
SQL> desc department;
```

This will give the list of all fields, it's type and default Null info of the table or view.

Answer (score -5):

you can use the ANSI catalog views, should work for most RDBMs

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns c
join information_schema.tables t on c.table_name = t.table_name
where table_type = 'view'
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle has these. Our Oracle install does not, and I couldn't find any reference for it...